# Unknown character literal appended at the end of a string in C#

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-communication

I am working on a Zigbee Wireless Electronic Notice display. I am using Arduino Nano. The basic idea is to get text from the computer and display it on an LCD connected to the Arduino. I am using Zigbee as the wireless communication medium.I made an interface in C# for sending the text to the microcontroller using the Serial Communication library in C#. Everything is working as expected but one problem I'm encountering is that, the text being displayed on the LCD has some unknown character literal(s) at the end of each string of text sent.

//For instance if i send: "Welcome home"

//output on LCD: Welcome home#

And this is my code for sending text through the serial port:

serialPort.writeLine(message);

I want the output to be the same as my input without any character literal(s) appended at the end.

Comment: That's weird. It may have something to do with the EOL character. Is it always '#'?

Comment: I actually cannot describe the character literal but it looks like that.

Comment: I suspect it is \r

Comment: Yeah, but how do i get rid of  '\r'  in my string?

Comment: Try `write` instead of `writeline` (which appends CR LF characters)

Comment: Exactly the answer i was looking for. Richardissimo, you are a life saver. Thanks very much!